# What does "video output" mean in media players?

Tags: video, media

What does "video output" mean in the context of media players?

Possible values are: `x11`, `xv`, `vdpau` etc. Are these drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're APIs. "x11" is raw [bit-blitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) (old and slow, almost never what you want to use barring bugs in the other APIs); "xv" is the [X Video extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_video_extension) (most cross-hardware compatible); "vdpau" is [Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) (nVidia-only).